# How to make a responsive bootstrap website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After, I customize my bootstrap website. I try to resize the media screen to different size from a computer one to mobile and tablet but I found out that it's not responsive to the media screen. I'm an absolute beginner to responsive websites. Please guide me on what can I do next ?

Comment: Could please share some codes & create fiddle, so that we can help you out. Check your browser console as we for any error related to bootstrap css file loading.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could have multiple causes. In genersal what you need to do next is implement either `css media queries` or properly tag HTML with bootstrap classes for responsiveness and make sure that the bootstrap CSS stylesheet is linked correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I do have to implement proper bootstrap classes. Thank you. Do I still need media queries for bootstrap ? Bootstrap has its own built in media queries.